# asp.net image src not showing from database in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am facing very rear problem. I am trying to bind images path from database using listview control. Listview gets bind but img is not showing up. When I look at inspect I cant's see src attribute in img tag. Listview gets bind perfectly and path is also correct. If you see below screenshot & see the highlighted line which is that img tag which is missing src attribute.
[image]

```
<div class="row">
        <asp:ListView ID="subCategoriesList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img id="myimag" runat="server" src='<%# Eval("icon") %>' />
                        <br /><%# Eval("name") %>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
```

ListviewBind Code

```
private void bindSubCatgoriesRightSide()
{
    try {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio2").ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr)) {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE type = 'product' and category = 'mobile' and status = 'active'";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    subCategoriesList.DataSource = dt;
                    subCategoriesList.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `<%# Eval("icon") %>` give you anything? What happens if you just put it in a span tag instead of trying to use it as the image URL? Does it give you the correct URL to an image?

Comment: @mason No. I tried to put <%# Eval("icon") in span. It didn't shown. Span tag also returned empty

Comment: So now you need to investigate your data source, make sure it's getting the data you expect.

Comment: show the code how you are trying to bind the data With ListView

Comment: @mason It's just not getting column icon which is image path. If I try to bind any other column from same table then it works perfectly

Comment: Like I said, you need to check out the data source and make sure it contains the data you expect.

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan Updated my post with Bind Code

Comment: @mason Yes datatable contains 'icon' column and it has value in it

Comment: @SUN does that image URL is working in browser ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at the wrong output section, in your listview item template, you are wrapping the image in `<div class="col-md-3"></div` ...

but in the screenshot, the image is wrapped in `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-bottom"></div`

Unless you are changing the classes with JS

Comment: Sorry I attached wrong image. But problem is there. I attached correct image for your reference

Comment: can you give an example of `icon` column contents?